Import a script from a parent's subdir, with a filename and dirname starting with digits
I know the usual Python import system, packages, __init__.py, the __import__ function (see In python, how to import filename starts with a number), etc. I know the classic How do I import other Python files? answers.
Disclaimer: I know the following is not a common file-structure, but sometimes you have to quickly deal with legacy code, without refactoring it.
|
|- 1 UTILS
|     |-  123myscript.py
|- 2 TESTS
|     |-  test.py

When running test.py, how can I import 123myscript.py, without mangling with the sys.path.append?
Is it possible with importlib? I haven't been able to do it with:
importlib.import_module("../1 UTILS/123myscript.py", package=None)


Take a look at this: https://github.com/tortoise/aerich/blob/51117867a690884531539be797508062a919e3c6/aerich/utils.py#L97

check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-can-i-import-a-module-dynamically-given-the-full-path

The importlib.import_module function only works with module names in the Python module namespace. It does not accept file paths because it relies on Python’s module search paths (e.g., sys.path) to locate modules.
To import a module from a specific file path, you should use importlib.util functions as shown in @simon answer

A pragmatic answer is given in the related question to which  Andrio Skur's comment provides a link. Indeed it uses importlib.
Adapted to your case, this could look as follows. Here, I assume

Python 3.5+ is used (I tried with 3.11.9);
the folder structure is exactly as given in your question;
the file 123myscript.py contains the following code:
# Contents of `1 UTILS/123myscript.py`
def do_something():
    return 42



Then, a successful import of 123myscript.py in test.py would be, for example:
# Contents of `2 TESTS/test.py`
import importlib.util
from pathlib import Path

location = Path(__file__).parents[1] / "1 UTILS" / "123myscript.py"

spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(location.stem, location)
# ^ Instead of `location.stem` (thus "123myscript"), you can use an arbitrary name
myscript = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(myscript)
assert myscript.do_something() == 42

Note that I don't know whether there are any dependencies in 123myscript.py, which might make the setup more complicated.

I have tried a few approaches, but this one works: We first make a symbolic link "1 UTILS/123myscript.py" -> "2 TESTS/myscript.py", then import via the importlib library. Here is the content of file "2 TESTS/test.py":
# File: 2 TESTS/test.py

import importlib
import pathlib

# Create symlink "1 UTILS/123myscript.py" -> "2 TESTS/myscript.py"
utils_dir = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.with_name("1 UTILS")
myscript_path = utils_dir / "123myscript.py"
temp = pathlib.Path(__file__).with_name("myscript.py")
temp.symlink_to(myscript_path)

# Import and clean up
myscript = importlib.import_module("myscript")
temp.unlink()
# Now we can work with the `myscript` module

Other approaches I tried and failed

cd into "1 UTILS" before import
Add absolute path for "1 UTILS" to sys.path before import

